# Configure microservices security using JWT OAuth2 in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2-identity-server

My idea is to configure microservices security pattern for APIs and SPA security pattern for web application to make our hybrid mobile apps and webapps work with WSO2 IS.

I configured IdP and SP as mentioned in the documentation. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+JWT+Grant+Type. I am not able to get this working.

```
<SupportedGrantType>
 <GrantTypeName>urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer</GrantTypeName>
 <GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.grant.jwt.JWTBearerGrantHandler</GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>
 <GrantTypeValidatorImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.grant.jwt.JWTGrantValidator</GrantTypeValidatorImplClass>
</SupportedGrantType>
```

> [2016-10-23 07:01:32,115] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.clientauth.AbstractClientAuthHandler}
>   -  Grant type : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer Strict client validation set to : null
>       [2016-10-23 07:01:32,118] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Client
>   credentials were fetched from the database.
>
> [2016-10-23 07:01:32,118] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Successfully
>   authenticated the client with client id : VY3zPlWNRgm3BqJWmHtYXe2ym08a
>
> [2016-10-23 07:01:32,118] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler}
>   -  Unsupported Grant Type : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer for client id :
>   VY3zPlWNRgm3BqJWmHtYXe2ym08a
>
> [2016-10-23 07:01:32,118] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} - 
>   OAuth-Error-Code=unauthorized_client
>   client-id=VY3zPlWNRgm3BqJWmHtYXe2ym08a
>   grant-type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer scope=

Comment: Did you create this SP after you added the grant type config/jars?
Can you try creating a new SP and getting an access token using JWT grant type? Also what is the version of IS you are trying this out with?

Answer (score 1):

JWT Bearer Grant is supported with IS 5.1.0

For the version to support IS 5.2.0 please follow up the jira [2]

[1] https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/isconnector/details/8affec9a-706f-4e72-83ec-f65c42895d40

[2] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ISCONNECT-34

Answer (score 0):

Please try now with version 1.0.3[1] which is compatible with IS 5.2.0.

[1] https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/isconnector/details/8affec9a-706f-4e72-83ec-f65c42895d40